# Scraping dates from Github using next_element

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** dates from Github in commit's section.
To **scrape** author I use:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/commits/master'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
author = [author.text for author in soup.find_all("a",class_="commit-author")]
```

It returns author who did commit to given project, but I also want to **scrape** the date for each commit. I tried:

```
dates = [date for date in soup.find("a",class_="commit-author").next_element.next_element.next_element]
```

Unfortunately it return only 1 date. I know it's caused because of using *find*, but when I want to use *find_all*, I got AttributeError, that ResultSet object has no attribute *next_element*. So is there any other way to get all dates?

Comment: Is there a specific `USER` or is the problem with any user?

Comment: @JackFleeting any user. I just didn't provide any nicknames and projects

Comment: I'm getting a "page not found" error.

Comment: @JackFleeting - instead of USER use any user you find on github, and instead of PROJECT any his repo

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

Try running it this way on your favorite user and project and see if it works:

```
author = soup.find_all("a",class_="commit-author")
for i in author:
    print("Author: ",i.text,"Date: ",i.next_element.next_element.next_element.text)
```

Comment: I just find other solution. I figured out that I can use relative-time as a tag to find dates